# I want the image to expand to the size of the card

Tags: flutter, image, card

I'm trying to put an image inside the card, but the image is overflowed

this is my code:

```
Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        elevation: 5.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(width: 0.1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [AppColors.secundary, Colors.lime],
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                AppImages.audi1,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Acidente'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

look how you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with stack and fitted box and if change the position of text, you will use `Align` widget

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>
             FittedBox(
                 child: Image.asset(
                AppImages.audi1,
              ),
               fit: BoxFit.fill,
             ),
              
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Acidente'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```